# Android, Tab layout which has listfragment from json parsing

Tags: android, json, tabs, android-listfragment

i'm trying to build android app which has tab layout which also has listfragment. i want total of three tabs, first home, second listview and third when clicked on listview it switches to third tabs and show some information all using json parsing.
i'm using this tutorials as a reference http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/
and for listview i'm using following - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/
Now the question is that how can i change listActivity to listFragment?

How can i turn this code from Listactivity to Listfragment?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.androidhive.helper.AlertDialogManager;
import com.example.androidhive.helper.ConnectionDetector;
import com.example.androidhive.helper.JSONParser;

public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;

    // albums JSONArray
    JSONArray albums = null;

    // albums JSON url
    private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "http://api.androidhive.info/songs/albums.php";

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_SONGS_COUNT = "songs_count";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check for internet connection
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(AlbumsActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Hashmap for ListView
        albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading Albums JSON in Background Thread
        new LoadAlbums().execute();

        // get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        /**
         * Listview item click listener
         * TrackListActivity will be lauched by passing album id
         * */
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // on selecting a single album
                // TrackListActivity will be launched to show tracks inside the album
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);

                // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album
                String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);               

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });     
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all Albums by making http request
     * */
    class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Listing Albums ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Albums JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

            try {               
                albums = new JSONArray(json);

                if (albums != null) {
                    // looping through All albums
                    for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item values in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        albumsList.add(map);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList,
                            R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                    TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Fragment are used to have reusable components. Difference between listActivity and ListFragment is not very vast. Tabs are old, you can use one of this http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: thanks, let me give it try. But don't i need to switch listActivity to listfragment? it was giving me lots of errors, not sure how to use json in listfragment.

Comment: if you can show your code, then I will be able to help you.

Comment: i have added to original question.