# Listfragment in android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-listfragment

How can i trigger new fragment or class opens up when each list item is selected?
Basically i want new fragment to be youtube fragment. when "Android" is selected particular youtube link is pass to that fragment. Same goes to other list items.

```
import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddingList extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener{
  String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux" };

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }



 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int position, long id) {

  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Item clicked: " + values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
}
```

have some errors:

```
import android.R.string;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddingList extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener{
  String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux" };

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }



 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
     FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.yourcontainer, new Home());
  //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Item clicked: " + values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setonItemClickListner()`, and then call `fragment`

like

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.yourcontainer, new YourClass()).commit();
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i'm sorry but i'm new to android developemnt. i'm getting error in fragmentManger and yourcontianer.  public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
  FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.yourcontainer, new Home());

Comment: what error you are getting ? On which os version you are working on? Means android 2.3 or 4.0?

Comment: 4.0 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction to android.app.FragmentTransaction,

Comment: Do not use support fragment library, android 4.0 has it already. remove import. and re import android.fragment.

Comment: Do not Use import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

Comment: Check you androidManifest.xml file. Check the minsdk value

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: you are developing for 2.3 probably. You need to use android support library, right click on your project and goto android tools and then add support library

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm still this error - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method beginTransaction() from the type FragmentManager

Comment: thank you, i'm not seeing any errors now, but what exactly goes in "yourconatiner" nothing happens when i clicked on any of the list item

Comment: :), it should be framelayout id if you want to use fragment replace method. Fragements are replace into something and that should be framelayout and the id of that would go in R.id.YOURCONTAINERID

Comment: new Home() class should extend Fragment otherwise it will throw an exception. If you want to start a new activity then code will  be " startActivity(this, newHome.Class) ". You can pass bundle to receive in new activity onStart or on onCreate

Comment: is there any way you could answer this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265358/android-tab-layout-which-has-listfragment-from-json-parsing